# How to set timer in Vuex?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuex

I just started learning Vue and Vuex. I am trying to set up a countdown timer that starts counting from 5 seconds when it is clicked. The logic has been placed in Vuex store for state management but I couldn't get the timer to run (it is stuck at 5 unchanged).

At parent (Home.vue)

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <Header 
    @change-game-button="changeGameButton"
     :gameInActive="gameInActive"
     :gameActive="gameActive"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from '../components/Header'

export default {
  name: 'Home',
  components: {
    Header,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      gameInActive: true,
      gameActive: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeGameButton() {
      console.log("Game button fired");
      this.gameInActive = !this.gameInActive;
      this.gameActive = !this.gameActive;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

At component (Header.vue)

```
<template>
  <div class="header-container">
    <StartResetButton 
    @btn-click="$emit('change-game-button')"
    :buttonText="gameInActive ? 'Start' : 'Restart'"
    :buttonColor="gameInActive ? '#90ee90' : '#FED8B1'"
    @click="gameInActive? 'resetCounter' : 'startCounter'"
    />
  </div>
  <div class="initialInstruction" v-if="gameInActive">{{ initialInstruction }}</div>
  <div class="gameStartTimer" v-if="gameActive">{{ gameStartTimer }}</div>
</template>

<script>
import StartResetButton from "./StartResetButton";
import { mapActions, mapMutations, mapState } from "vuex";

export default {
  components: {
    StartResetButton,
  },
  props: {
      gameInActive: Boolean,
      gameActive: Boolean,
  },
  computed: {
      ...mapState(["gameStartTimer", "initialInstruction"])
  },
  methods: {
    //   ...mapMutations(["countDown"]),
      ...mapActions(["startCounter", "resetCounter"])
  },
  emits: ['change-game-button']
};
</script>
```

At the store (index.js)

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

export default createStore({
  state: {
    gameStartTimer: 5,
    initialInstruction: "Press Start to Begin"
  },
  mutations: {
    stopCounter(state) {
      state.gameStartTimer = 5
    },
    counter(state) {
      if (state.gameStartTimer > 0) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          state.gameStartTimer--;
        }, 1000)
      }
    }
  },
  actions: {
    startCounter(context) {
      context.commit('counter')
    },
    resetCounter(context) {
      context.commit('stopCounter')
    }
  },
  modules: {
  }
})
```

StartResetButton.vue

```
<template>
  <button 
  class="btn"
  @click="onClick()" 
  :style="{ background: buttonColor }">
    {{ buttonText }}
  </button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "StartResetButton",
  props: {
    buttonText: String,
    buttonColor: String,
  },
  methods: {
      onClick() {
          this.$emit('btn-click')
      }
  }
};
</script>
```

Any tips on why the timer wouldn't fire?

Comment: Because of this flaky expression? `@click="gameInActive? 'resetCounter' : 'startCounter'"` . It evaluates to 'resetCounter' string, not method. Don't write more logic than you should in a template. Also mutations are supposed to be synchronous, you're trying to do actions' job there.

Comment: Thank you. I am simplifying the codes nows by placing most of the logic to actions. I have managed to get setTimeout to count down by 1, but it only reduced by 1 second and stopped there. I am in the process of figuring out how to loop through it until the 5 seconds are up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that this won't execute click handlers:

```
@click="gameInActive? 'resetCounter' : 'startCounter'"
```

`v-on` (`@`) value should be either a function that is used as event handler, or an expression that is evaluated on event. This expression doesn't result in `resetCounter`, etc function calls because `typeof (this.gameInActive? 'resetCounter' : 'startCounter') === 'string'`. It's preferable to provide a single handler that will make decisions instead of putting conditions into a template.

Vuex supports promises, it's preferable to use promise control flow for asynchronous actions. `setTimeout` callback is executed once. If it's supposed to decrement multiple times, `setTimeout` should be used in a loop with `await`, or `setInterval` should be used instead.

Mutations are synchronous and commonly fine-grained functions that access the state directly. There can be ones called `decrementCount`, `startCounter`, etc.

```
  state: {
    count: 5,
    counter: false
  },
  actions: {
    async startCounter({ state }) {
      state.counter = true;
      while (state.count > 0 && state.counter) {
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
        if (state.counter)
          state.count--;
      }
      state.counter = false;
    },
    resetCounter(context) {
      state.count = 5;
      state.counter = false;
    }
  },
```

Comment: Thank you, this works well. Just a question regarding setTimeout and setInterval, is it preferable to use setTimeout? I was researching the difference between the two and someone mentioned memory bleeds. Not that it makes a difference in a 5 second counter but I am more interested in what's the good practice in writing these codes.

Comment: None of them should cause memory leaks in modern browsers if done right. The difference is that the error will add up over long intervals with setTimeout but it results in more finegrained code. IIn this case `startCounter().then(...)` with setTimeout will resolve within 1s when a counter is aborted. With setInterval this could be faster but would require more complex abort mechanism to have control over it with a promise.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, click the StartResetButton.vue button and the function should be executed as follows.

1. @btn-click="$emit"('change-game-button') should be executed first, so that the gameInActive should be false.
2. startCounter action must be executed.

Use console.log to verify that it runs in the order intended. I can't see how it works because the post doesn't have the StartResetButton.vue code.

startCounter action then executes the counter mutation, which, if the function is executed normally, will stop at 4 because the counter mutation is executed only once.

I recommend that the counter mutation be modified by only reducing the gameStartTimer by 1 and executing the counter mutation every 1 second using the timeout if the gameStartTimer value in the startCounter action is greater than 0.

Comment: Thank you. I have added the StartResetButton.vue for your information. I am going through the files now per your suggestion and see what can be done.